# How to parallelize requests in django script run from the command line?

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing, python-asyncio

I have a local Django project and some scripts that execute requests in parallel, but the requests are always executed synchronously.

Here is a sample script that demonstrates the issue:

```py
import asyncio
import json

import requests
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


async def do_task(task):
    print(f"starting task {task}")
    response = requests.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
    response_json = json.loads(response.text)
    print(response_json)
    print(f"finished task {task}")


async def run():
    tasks = set()
    for i in range(5):
        task = asyncio.create_task(do_task(i))
        tasks.add(task)
        task.add_done_callback(tasks.discard)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

# python manage.py shell < path/to/scripts/test.py
if __name__ in ("__main__", "django.core.management.commands.shell"):
    print("==start==")
    async_to_sync(run)()
    print("==done==")
```

The output for this script is:

```
==start==
starting task 0
{...} # response
finished task 0
starting task 1
{...} # response
finished task 1
starting task 2
{...} # response
finished task 2
starting task 3
{...} # response
finished task 3
starting task 4
{...} # response
finished task 4
==done==
```

I would expect to see something closer to this (all tasks started at the same time):

```
==start==
starting task 0
starting task 1
starting task 2
starting task 3
starting task 4
{...} # response
{...} # response
{...} # response
{...} # response
{...} # response
finished task 0
finished task 1
finished task 2
finished task 3
finished task 4
==done==
```

Comment: `do_task` is blocking. You need to use an asyncio-aware library like aiohttp or httpx instead of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

requests blocks the main thread, similar to using `timer.sleep` instead of `asyncio.sleep`.

Using aiohttp solves the issue.

Thanks @dirn for the help!

```py
import asyncio
import json

import aiohttp
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync


async def do_task(task):
    print(f"starting task {task}")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1") as response:
            response_json = json.loads(await response.text())
            print(response_json)
    print(f"finished task {task}")


async def run():
    tasks = set()
    for i in range(10):
        task = asyncio.create_task(do_task(i))
        tasks.add(task)
        task.add_done_callback(tasks.discard)
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

# python mainsite/manage.py shell < mainsite/funds/scripts/test.py
if __name__ in ("__main__", "django.core.management.commands.shell"):
    print("==start==")
    async_to_sync(run)()
    print("==done==")
```